How do you insert rows for missing products per group in teradata sql
I want to retrieve a complete list of all products associated with each ID. This list should include products that are present in Table1, as well as any products that are not in Table1. For products that are not found in Table1, I want the product name to be marked as 'missing' or 'null' and still associated with the respective ID.
I have two tables as below
Table1



PROD NAME
ID
C




PRD1
A1.
1


PRD2.
A1.
3


PRD3.
A2.
22


PRD1.
A3
23



Table 2



PROD NAME
D
E




PRD1
11
2


PRD4.
4.
4


PRD3.
3.
4




Output for ID =A1



PROD NAME
ID
C
D
E




PRD1.
A1.
1.
11.
2


PRD2.
A1.
3.
?
?


PRD3.
A1.
?
3.
4


PRD4.
A1.
?
4.
4




Welcome to SO. It seems you want some sort of OUTER JOIN between these two tables, but the question is unclear. Please edit the question to add more detail and improve the examples (check the formatting help also).

Why is PRD4 associated specifically with ID A1, instead of ID being NULL for PRD4?

I want to retrieve a complete list of all products associated with each ID.

First, query for  all ID's and all PROD_NAME.
All ID's (subquery ids)
select DISTINCT ID from table1

All PROD_NAME (subquery prods)
select distinct PROD_NAME
   from table1
   union
   select distinct PROD_NAME
   from table2

We union list of PROD_NAME's from table1 and table2 and take DISTINCT one for PROD_NAME value.
Then we get  cartesian product of prods and ids - join every ID with every PROD_NAME.
select ids.ID,prods.PROD_NAME 
from
  (select distinct PROD_NAME
   from table1
   union
   select distinct PROD_NAME
   from table2
   ) prods
  ,(select DISTINCT ID from table1) ids

Finally, LEFT JOIN table1 and table2.
See example
select idprod.ID,idprod.PROD_NAME,C,D,E
from(
  select ids.ID,prods.PROD_NAME from
  (select distinct PROD_NAME
   from table1
   union
   select distinct PROD_NAME
   from table2
   ) prods
  ,(select DISTINCT ID from table1) ids
)idprod
left join table1 t1 on t1.PROD_NAME=idprod.PROD_NAME and t1.ID=idprod.ID
left join table2 t2 on t2.PROD_NAME=idprod.PROD_NAME
-- where idprod.ID ='A1'
order by idprod.id,idprod.prod_name

See example for SQL Server
